# MySQL php edition table and adding the same value on another table

Tags: php, mysql

I actually developping an intranet solution for my work,
The thing is that i want to update and operation and add the same result into one of my 3 different tables depending on the -operation- option,
in my initial code if the modification is ok the data will be updated into "taches_redaction" table,
in revenche i need to add 3 different rules,
soif operation is equal to 1 up date taches_redction and add the data into copie table,
soif operation is equal to 2 up date taches_redction and add the data into colla table,
soif operation is equal to 3 up date taches_redction and add the data into archive table,
all of this to have a precise historical record on echa changes in my operations and have some values to get statistics for each team member on the company...

```
<?php
include '../theme/header-global.php';
?>

<?php

/* 
 Allows user to edit specific entry in database
*/

 // creates the edit record form
 // since this form is used multiple times in this file, I have made it a function that is easily reusable
 function renderForm($serie, $user_id, $journee, $titre, $region, $role, $operation, $date, $error)
 {
 ?>


<div style="width:100%">

<center><h1>تحيين التوزيع</h1></center>


 <?php 
 // if there are any errors, display them
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 <form action="" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="serie" value="<?php echo $serie; ?>" readonly="readonly" />


<table cellpadding="3" cellpadding="3" align="center" id=MyTable width="650">


<tr>
<td align="center">الإسم</td>
<td align="center">
<?php
        // get results from database
    $usage = mysql_query("SELECT t.* , o.* FROM users t,taches_redaction o WHERE t.id=o.user_id GROUP BY user_name") 
        or die(mysql_error());  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $usage )) {
 if($row['user_id'] == $user_id) 
    {       // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo '' . $row['user_name'] . '';
} else {
  // do something else
        echo '';
}
}
?>
</td>
<td>
<select id="user_id" name="user_id">
            <option value="0"></option>
<?php
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

if($row['id'] == $user_id) 
{
        echo '<option value=' . $row['id'] . ' selected=selected>' . $row['user_name'] . '</option>';
} else {
  // do something else
        echo '<option value=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['user_name'] . '</option>';
}
}
 ?>
        </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">اليومية</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="journee" value="<?php echo $journee; ?>" /></td>
<td></td>
</tr>




<tr>
<td align="center">الرسم العقاري</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="text" name="titre" value="<?php echo $titre; ?>" />
<?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '4' ) echo 'FR'; ?>      
<?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '1')  echo 'بن عروس'; ?>
<?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '2')  echo 'زغوان'; ?>
<?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '3')  echo 'تونس'; ?>
</td>
<td>
<select name="region">
<option value="4" <?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '4' ) echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>FR</option>      
<option value="1" <?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '1')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>بن عروس</option>
<option value="2" <?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '2')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>زغوان</option>
<option value="3" <?php if (!empty($region) && $region == '3')  echo 'selected = "selected"'; ?>>تونس</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>




<tr>
<td align="center">المهام</td>
<td align="center">
 <select id="role" name="role">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option></option>
        </select>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">العملية</td>
<td align="center">
<?php

$fonki = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fonctions")
        or die(mysql_error());  

        // get results from database
    $operage = mysql_query("SELECT t.* , o.* FROM taches_redaction t,operations o WHERE t.operation=o.oper_id GROUP BY operation") 
        or die(mysql_error());  

    // display data in table
/*  echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>"; */
    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $operage )) {
 if($row['oper_id'] == $operation) 
    {       // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo '' . $row['operation_name'] . '';
} else {
  // do something else
        echo '';
}
}
?>
</td>
<?php
    echo "<td>
    <select name=operation>
    <option value =0></option>";
 include "../render/render_operation-selected.php";
    echo "</select>
    </td>";
?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>تاريخ التحيين</td>
<td>
<?php
        echo '' . $row['date'] . '';
?>
</td>

<td style="direction:rtl;">
<?php echo "<input type='text' value='".date('o/m/d')."' style='width: 148px;' name='date' readonly=readonly>";?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="تغيير" class="brd"></td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" value="إلغاء" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" class="bbl">
</td>

</tr>
 </table>

 <?php
 }



 // connect to the database

 // check if the form has been submitted. If it has, process the form and save it to the database
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 { 
 // confirm that the 'id' value is a valid integer before getting the form data
 if (is_numeric($_POST['serie']))
 {
 // get form data, making sure it is valid
 $serie = $_POST['serie'];
 $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_id']));
 $journee = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['journee']));
 $titre = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']));
 $region = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['region']));
 $role = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['role']));
 $operation = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['operation']));
 $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));

 // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
 if ($user_id == '' || $journee == '' || $titre == '' || $region == '' || $role == '' || $operation =='' || $date =='')
 {
 // generate error message
 $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

 //error, display form
 renderForm($serie, $user_id, $journee, $titre, $region, $role , $operation, $date, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 // save the data to the database
 mysql_query("UPDATE taches_redaction SET user_id='$user_id', journee='$journee', titre='$titre', region='$region', role='$role', operation='$operation', date='$date' WHERE serie='$serie'") 
 /* frere update */

/*
 AND

 mysql_query("INSERT copie SET user_id='$user_id', journee='$journee', titre='$titre', region='$region', role='$role', operation='$operation', date='$date'")

 AND

 mysql_query("INSERT colla SET user_id='$user_id', journee='$journee', titre='$titre', region='$region', role='$role', operation='$operation', date='$date'")

 AND

 mysql_query("INSERT archive SET user_id='$user_id', journee='$journee', titre='$titre', region='$region', role='$role', operation='$operation', date='$date'")
*/ 
 or die(mysql_error()); 



 // once saved, redirect back to the view page
/* header('Refresh: 2; URL = taches_view.php');
 */

  }
 }
 else
 {
 // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
 else
 // if the form hasn't been submitted, get the data from the db and display the form
 {

 // get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
 if (isset($_GET['serie']) && is_numeric($_GET['serie']) && $_GET['serie'] > 0)
 {
 // query db
 $serie = $_GET['serie'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM taches_redaction WHERE serie=$serie")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {

 // get data from db
 $serie = $row['serie'];
 $user_id = $row['user_id'];
 $journee = $row['journee'];
 $titre = $row['titre'];
 $region = $row['region'];
 $role = $row['role'];
 $operation = $row['operation'];
 $date = $row['date'];

 // show form
 renderForm($serie, $user_id, $journee, $titre, $region, $role, $operation, $date, '');
 }
 else
 // if no match, display result
 {
 echo "No results!";
 }
 }
 else
 // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value, display an error
 {
 echo 'Error!';
 }
 }
?>




  <!-- end .content --></div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>



<?php
include '../theme/footer-global.php';
?>
```

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY is unlikely to be something that you'd want here.

Comment: nobody can solve this ? i am trying to figure it out but still lost in translation...